# Additional .mp4 decoders for VideoView

Tags: android, video, mp4

I am building an app that downloads .mp4 files from the Internet and plays them.

It seems there are no decoders for this particular video type, and I only get audio, no picture. The same thing happens with the standalone player, so it is not a problem with the program or file.

Is it possible to use a user library for the decoding and plug it into VideView?

The .mp4 in question can be found here: https://www.coursera.org/modelthinking/lecture/preview_view?lecture_id=17

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are testing on the emulator, audio with no picture is pretty typical. Only test video apps on hardware.

Comment: Thanks. It's the hardware too, a Samsung Galaxy Mini. The file is encoded with the H.264 codec with High Profile. The only solution I can think is to transcode the file with a non-real time transcoder, but I don't think there is any pure Java library that can do this.